# How do you generate pool_transactions_genesis and domain_transactions_genesis?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I'm experimenting with creating a Hyperledger-Indy network and have been following the [readthedocs](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/node/en/latest/start-nodes.html).

I can spin up blank indy-node docker containers and have been able to generate their keys using `init_indy_node` with my seed.

I can't find instructions on how to generate **pool_transactions_genesis** and **domain_transactions_genesis** using the keys generated above. The only thing I can find is the command `generate_indy_pool_transactions` but this just creates a generic bootstrap sandbox network that always has the same keys and does not use the ones created above using my selected seed.

How do you generate these genesis files?

Answer (score 5):

As described [start-nodes.md](http://in%20https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node/blob/master/docs/source/start-nodes.md), in order to setup a pool the following actions are needed:

- set Network name in config file
- generate keys (`init_indy_node` script can be used for this)
- provide genesis transactions files which will be a basis of initial Pool

Indy doesn't have any genesis files going with it since this is up to Indy-based Networks (such as [Sovrin genesis](https://github.com/sovrin-foundation/sovrin/tree/master/sovrin)).

What Indy has is a `generate_indy_pool_transactions` script which should be used for test purposes only. It generates keys based on the Nodes names (so if the same Node names are passed there, then the keys will be the same every time).

So, there are the following options on how to create genesis files in Indy:

1. Create them manually.
2. Contribute to Indy creating a script for generation (I think the logic from `generate_indy_pool_transactions` can be used for this).
3. Run `generate_indy_pool_transactions` (which will generate keys and genesis files), then re-init keys correctly and modify the genesis files from `generate_indy_pool_transactions` to point to correct keys.

Comment: Hello Alexander, if you found exactly the steps(not for a test network), please post them. It's so confusing.

Answer (score -1):

To generate pool_transactions_genesis and domain_transactions_genesis file, you have to use indy-plenum.

You can find details on the following tutorial:

https://taseen-junaid.medium.com/hyperledger-indy-custom-network-with-indy-node-plenum-protocol-ledger-85fd10eb5bf5

You can find the code base of that tutorial into following link:

https://github.com/Ta-SeenJunaid/Hyperledger-Indy-Tutorial